Transient States of Markov Chain Intuition
I know the standard definition of recurrent and transient states of Markov chain. A state $j$ is called recurrent if starting from $j$, the chain eventually returns to $j$ with probability 1. Otherwise its called transient. I want to intuitively understand transient states, in particular from the transition diagrams. Is my understanding correct that a state $i$ is transient if and only if there exists a state $j$ such that starting from $i$ there is a way to reach $j$, however starting from $j$ there is no way to reach $i$?

So is my statement correct for finite state markov chains?

Yes. Your statement is correct for finite state Markov chains. Here's an intuitive explanation. Assume that each state that can be reached from $i$ has positive probability of returning to $i$. One of those states, $j$ will be visited infinitely many times (why?) and each visit, there is fixed positive probability of returning to $i$ before returning to $j$. So eventually, one of these IID trials will be a success.

In general, the answer is NO.
Example
Consider the following MC on $\{1,2,\dots\}$: we jump from $i$ to $i+1$ with probability $1-2^{-i}$ and to $i$ to $1$ with probability $2^{-i}$.
Therefore:

There is a way to get from any state $i_1$ to state $i_2$: jump from $i_1$ to $1$ and then jump step-by-step to $i_2$.

Yet: all states are transient. Let's see why.


In order to return to $i$, the process must return first to $1$. The probability of never returning to $i$ is larger or equal to the probability of moving one step to the right every step This is equal to
$$(1-2^{-i})(1-2^{-(i+1)}) \dots = \prod_{j\ge i} (1-2^{-j})>0,$$
because $\sum_{j\ge i}2^{-j}<\infty$. Therefore $i$ is transient.

Are there any counterexamples for finite state Markov Chains?

No. For a finite state chain transience of $i$  is equivalent to having a path for some $j$ and no path from $j$ to $i$.
